# How To Set On Click Listener To ListView Items Loaded From Web Server

Tags: android, json, listview, dynamic, web

I Was Trying To Implement Web Service In My Application So That I Can Add New Items Into A ListView Without Having To Update My Application Each Time..

I found a lot of tutorials on how to populate a listview from web server/json

But I wasn't able to figure out how to apply onclicklistener to the items loaded from web server/ json

This is the code that I am using without a web service :

```
case 6:
        desc = "blah blah blah";
        owner = "blah blah blah";
        s1 = "blah blah blah";
        s2 = "blah blah blah";
        s3 = "blah blah blah";
        s4 = "blah blah blah";
        modpage = "blah blah blah";
        download = "blah blah blah";
        name = "blah blah blah";

        stuff = new Bundle();
        stuff.putString("description", desc);
        stuff.putString("maker", owner);
        stuff.putString("screen1", s1);
        stuff.putString("screen2", s2);
        stuff.putString("screen3", s3);
        stuff.putString("screen4", s4);
        stuff.putString("officialmodpage", modpage);
        stuff.putString("downloadlink", download);
        stuff.putString("modname", name);

        launchAct = new Intent(this, blahblahblah.class);
        launchAct.putExtras(stuff);
        startActivity(launchAct);
        break;
```

Different items have different disc, owner etc..
And all of these strings are passed to an activity..All items in the listview pass these string to the same activity

I want the listview item to show only a title like : "BLAH" and once that item is clicked,I want all the data associated with the item to pass to the next activity...

Any tutorials or help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: It does not matter from where you are loading your data from. Its to the views that you are going to add the listner  and not to the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply **use the OnClickListener**

As here

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

       Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
       prestationEco str=(prestationEco)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But before that you have to create the list.

You can get details from [Here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html)

Please feel free to ask any thing else.

Hope it help.

Thanks